# Internet Explorer download notification on HTTPS

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, https, download, notifications

I have a Silverlight application deployed on a HTTPS server. My applications generates reports that are saved as PDF files. Whenever a user tries to download a file from my application from IE, he gets a notification under the toolbar asking him if he really wants to download the file. If you agree, then IE reloads the page, sending the user back to the login page of my application. After logging again, the user can download any file, but this is very annoying for the user. How can I resolve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Not quite seeing how silverlight is used here.  Exactly how does the application provide the "download a file" feature to the user?

Comment: I am redirecting the user to an aspx that generates a document based on a ID provided in the QueryString. I set the ContentType of the Response and the content-disposition in order to force the browser to show a download file window.

Answer (score 2):

**If you know who your users are (condition)**, you might ask them to put your website under their list of Trusted Sites, which will avoid the annoying notification bars.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the download in such a way that it's obviously a user-initiated action. I'm not sure if Silverlight offers a method for this.